# Call InitializeComponent without going through the constructor by reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm developing an application that needs to explore all the UserControls/Forms of a library in a similar way that the Designer of Visual Studio does.

The first part is easy, as I can get all the classes with normal reflection. My problem is when trying to create a new instance, I need to pass the required parameters to the constructor in case there's no empty one.

The solution I'm looking for is to bypass in some way the constructor so I can instantiate the class and then call `InitializeComponent` in that instance.

How Visual Studio's designer is able to create a new instance for a class with no empty constructor?

I've tried to create a new instance via the `Assembly.CreateInstance` but if no empty constructor is found an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it is create an unitialized object via `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` which creates an object without calling the constructor. Then, get the constructor from the System.Windows.Forms.Form base class and call the constructor over the previously created object.

Then, the InitializeComponent can be directly called and the ControlCollection could be accesed.

The following snippet should get the expected results:

```
        object GetValidInstance(Type toInstantiate)
        {
            object BaseInstance = System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(toInstantiate);
            System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo frmCtor = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Form).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo miInitialize = toInstantiate.GetMethod("InitializeComponent", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

            frmCtor.Invoke(BaseInstance, null);

            miInitialize.Invoke(BaseInstance, null);

            return BaseInstance;
        }
```